# Pathauto based on Primary Links

Tags: php, drupal, module, pathauto

I'm trying to set up pathauto to generate clean URLs based on my primary links. So About > Executives / Board would be about/executives-board. I've used the [menupath-raw] token for this which is creating the alias:

About/Executives / Board

It's not removing the slash and leaving in spaces. Also, it's not converting to lowercase. I've got all of these options set (remove slash, replace space with dash, convert to lowercase).

What else could be wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: I tried this out and I'm getting the same results. +1 for a good question

Comment: Have you tried playing with the pathauto replacement and cahracter-blacklist settings?

Answer (score 1):

Solution is to upgrade to the latest development release of both Pathauto and Token modules. See http://drupal.org/node/881270 for the bug.

Comment: +1 for nice forensic work. @all: Please use the dev version dated after September 27th, 2010. #881270 was fixed on that date. See CVS messages http://drupal.org/project/cvs/17345